# dplyr lag with n from column values

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to use column values as *n* in a *dplyr::lag* function?

Reproducible example:

```
DF <- data.frame(
    V = runif(1000, min=-100, max=100), 
    nlag = as.integer(runif(1000, min=1, max=10))
) %>% 
mutate(Vlag = lag(V, n = nlag))
```

I get this error:

> Error: Evaluation error: `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not integer of length 1000.

Is there any other alternative?

**Update:**

How do we solve the same problem within groups?

Reproducible example:

```
DF <- data.frame(
    V = runif(1000, min=-100, max=100),
    nlag = as.integer(runif(1000, min=1, max=10)),
    type = sample(1:4, replace=TRUE)
) %>%
group_by(type) %>% 
mutate(Vlag = lag(V, n = nlag))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation at `?lag` says

> n
>   a positive integer of length 1, giving the number of positions to lead or lag by

So it is not possible to give any number greater than `length = 1` .

We can however generate the index to get `V` value by subtracting the current row index with the corresponding `nlag` value and then we use that index to get the lagged `V` value.

```
df$lag_value <- sapply(seq_along(df$nlag), function(x) {
      indx = x - df$nlag[x]
     if(indx > 0)
        df$V[indx]
     else
        NA
})
df

#          V nlag lag_value
#1  51.30453    6        NA
#2 -66.33709    4        NA
#3  95.45096    9        NA
#4  44.54434    3  51.30453
#5  62.00180    3 -66.33709
#6 -18.43012    4 -66.33709
```

**Update**

If we want to do this by groups we can split them by `type` column and apply the same operation.

```
df$lag_value <- unlist(lapply(split(df, df$type), function(x) 
        sapply(seq_along(x$nlag), function(y) {
          indx = y - x$nlag[y]
          if(indx > 0)
            x$V[indx]
          else
             NA
})))
```

**data**

```
df <- head(DF)
```

Answer (score 4):

`nlag` must have lenth 1, try something like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  V = runif(1000, min=-100, max=100), 
  nlag = as.integer(runif(1000, min=1, max=10))
) %>%  mutate(Vlag = V[if_else((row_number() - nlag) < 1, as.integer(NA), row_number() - nlag)])
                V nlag         Vlag
1     -6.72598341    4           NA
2    -84.67472238    2           NA
3     -4.98048104    7           NA
4      2.64957272    4           NA
5     82.16284532    4  -6.72598341
6     28.93483448    9           NA
7     88.16730371    3   2.64957272
8     42.31721302    7  -6.72598341
9    -38.12659876    1  42.31721302
10    74.62628153    3  88.16730371
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using the `purrr`-package. `map2_dbl` takes two vectors (or to lists) of the same length as an input and iterates over them simultaneously. Then a `double` is returned. Inside the `map`-call the `lag` of V is calculated with the specified `nlag and then only the current row returned.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DF %>% 
  mutate(Vlag = map2_dbl(nlag, row_number(), ~ lag(V, n = .x)[.y]))

# A tibble: 20 x 3
#         V  nlag  Vlag
#     <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1  83.0      9  NA  
#  2  87.4      2  NA  
#  3 -42.8      9  NA  
#  4  66.1      9  NA  
#  5  28.3      1  66.1
#  6   3.82     5  83.0
#  7  47.3      4 -42.8
#  8 -73.1      9  NA  
#  9  31.4      5  66.1
# 10  41.0      8  87.4
# ...
```

**Data**
When using random numbers as an example you should specify a seed. Also in this case a smaller number of rows is sufficient to show the problem.

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- tibble(V = runif(20, min=-100, max=100), 
             nlag = as.integer(runif(20, min=1, max=10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little cleaner than the current answers:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, nlag) %>% 
  mutate(Vlag = dplyr::lag(V, n = nlag[1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Since it's grouped `nlag` all the indexes are the same, so taking the first works ok.