# dplyr::lead or data.table::shift refer to variable value rather than scalar

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lead

Given:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        rep(2, 5), rep(3, 3)),
                 dates = as.Date(c("2015-01-01",
                                   "2015-01-02",
                                   "2015-01-02",
                                   "2015-01-03",
                                   "2015-01-04",
                                   "2015-02-22",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-25",
                                   "2015-03-13",
                                   "2015-03-14",
                                   "2015-03-15")),
                 indicator = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                               0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                               0, 1, 0),
                 final_date = as.Date(rep(NA, 13))) %>% 
  group_by(id, dates) %>% 
  mutate(repeat_days = n())
df
#       id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
#    <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
#  1     1 2015-01-01         0 NA                   1
#  2     1 2015-01-02         1 NA                   2
#  3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
#  4     1 2015-01-03         0 NA                   1
#  5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
#  6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
#  7     2 2015-02-23         1 NA                   3
#  8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#  9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
# 10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
# 11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
# 12     3 2015-03-14         1 NA                   1
# 13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
```

Based on a condition (`indicator == 1`), I want to `lead` `dates` by a value in a variable (`repeat_days`) rather than supplying a scaler value so my desired output looks like:

```
#df_final
#       id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
#    <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
#  1     1 2015-01-01         0 NA                   1
#  2     1 2015-01-02         1 2015-01-03           2
#  3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
#  4     1 2015-01-03         0 NA                   1
#  5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
#  6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
#  7     2 2015-02-23         1 2015-02-25           3
#  8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#  9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
# 10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
# 11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
# 12     3 2015-03-14         1 2015-03-15           1
# 13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
```

If we wanted to `lead` by a scalar e.g. `1`, this works:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(final_date = case_when(is.na(final_date) & indicator == 1 ~ 
                                  lead(dates, n = 1), TRUE ~ final_date))
```

But when I supply a variable it won't work as expected as its not a scalar:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(final_date = case_when(is.na(final_date) & indicator == 1 ~ 
                                  lead(dates, repeat_days), TRUE ~ final_date)) 
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `final_date`.
# i `final_date = case_when(...)`.
# x `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not an integer vector of length 5.
# i The error occurred in group 1: id = 1.
```

This won't work either as it refers to the first occurrence of `repeat_days` by group which is 1 in all these cases:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(final_date = case_when(is.na(final_date) & indicator == 1 ~ 
                                  lead(dates, repeat_days[1]), TRUE ~ final_date))
```

Is there a way to refer to the row level value of `repeat_days` directly without creating an additional variable?

thanks

---

**EDIT**
thanks to @Maël nice answer:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(final_date = case_when(is.na(final_date) & indicator == 1 ~ 
                                  lead(dates, repeat_days[indicator == 1]), 
                                TRUE ~ final_date))
```

I should have made it clear that I could also have repeat `indicator == 1` per group so it would need to work on this dataset too:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                        rep(2, 5), rep(3, 3), 4, 4),
                 dates = as.Date(c("2015-01-01",
                                   "2015-01-02",
                                   "2015-01-02",
                                   "2015-01-03",
                                   "2015-01-04",
                                   "2015-02-22",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-23",
                                   "2015-02-25",
                                   "2015-03-13",
                                   "2015-03-14",
                                   "2015-03-15",
                                   "2015-04-15",
                                   "2015-04-16")),
                 indicator = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
                               0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                               0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
                 final_date = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", rep(NA, 14)))) %>% 
  group_by(id, dates) %>% 
  mutate(repeat_days = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
df
#       id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
#    <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
#  1     1 2015-01-01         0 2015-01-01           1
#  2     1 2015-01-02         1 NA                   2
#  3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
#  4     1 2015-01-03         1 NA                   1
#  5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
#  6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
#  7     2 2015-02-23         1 NA                   3
#  8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#  9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
# 10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
# 11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
# 12     3 2015-03-14         1 NA                   1
# 13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
# 14     4 2015-04-15         0 NA                   1
# 15     4 2015-04-16         1 NA                   1
```

Note for `id == 4`, there is no lead date, so I want it to default to their current line in that case. Also the first row now already has a `final_date` value in it, hence the requirement to use `case_when` or something similar.

Desired output:

```
#       id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
#    <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
#  1     1 2015-01-01         0 2015-01-01           1
#  2     1 2015-01-02         1 2015-01-03           2
#  3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
#  4     1 2015-01-03         1 2015-01-04           1
#  5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
#  6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
#  7     2 2015-02-23         1 2015-02-25           3
#  8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#  9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
# 10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
# 11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
# 12     3 2015-03-14         1 2015-03-15           1
# 13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
# 14     4 2015-04-15         0 NA                   1
# 15     4 2015-04-16         1 2015-04-16           1
```

Related links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772134/dplyr-how-to-lag-by-group), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639569/create-lag-lead-variable-in-dplyr-with-dynamic-number-of-position) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053022/dplyr-lag-with-n-from-column-values) but I couldn't implement something similar on this particular case with conditions. Happy to see `data.table` (`shift`?) solutions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler to write a `lead` function that takes a vector of `n`s. Below I call this function `lead2`. The rest of your code remains the same.

*Update*: You further clarify that, if `indicator = 1` but there is no lead date, the final_date should be filled in with the current date. This can be implemented with `dplyr::coalesce` which finds the first non-null element in a vector. It's an analogue to the SQL COALESCE operator.

```r
library("tidyverse")

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    rep(2, 5), rep(3, 3), 4, 4
  ),
  dates = as.Date(c(
    "2015-01-01",
    "2015-01-02",
    "2015-01-02",
    "2015-01-03",
    "2015-01-04",
    "2015-02-22",
    "2015-02-23",
    "2015-02-23",
    "2015-02-23",
    "2015-02-25",
    "2015-03-13",
    "2015-03-14",
    "2015-03-15",
    "2015-04-15",
    "2015-04-16"
  )),
  indicator = c(
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1
  ),
  final_date = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", rep(NA, 14)))
) %>%
  group_by(id, dates) %>%
  mutate(repeat_days = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

lead2 <- function(x, ns) {
  # x: vector of values
  # ns: vector of leads

  # Compute the target position for each element
  is <- seq_along(x) + ns
  x[is]
}

xs <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
ns <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
lead2(xs, ns)
#> [1] "b" "c" "e" NA  "f" NA

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    final_date = if_else(
      is.na(final_date) & indicator == 1,
        coalesce(lead2(dates, repeat_days), dates),
        final_date
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 15 × 5
#> # Groups:   id [4]
#>       id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
#>    <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
#>  1     1 2015-01-01         0 2015-01-01           1
#>  2     1 2015-01-02         1 2015-01-03           2
#>  3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
#>  4     1 2015-01-03         1 2015-01-04           1
#>  5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
#>  6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
#>  7     2 2015-02-23         1 2015-02-25           3
#>  8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#>  9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
#> 10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
#> 11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
#> 12     3 2015-03-14         1 2015-03-15           1
#> 13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
#> 14     4 2015-04-15         0 NA                   1
#> 15     4 2015-04-16         1 2015-04-16           1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm taking a look at your second example and I have a question: In row 4 indicator = 1 and repeat_days = 1 but final_date is not filled in with "2015-01-04 "; doesn't that break the logic?

Comment: i have written an explanation of this requirement in the edited question, essentially, if there is no lead value in the group, then it defaults to `dates`

Comment: This explains row #15. My question is about row #4 where the indicator is 1 but the final_date is not filled in.

Comment: apologies, typo it looks like!

Comment: I've updated the solution to use the current date in `dates` whenever there is no lead. Note however that row #4 is different from the proposed solution because I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Just realized that there is only one condition, so we don't need `case_when` and we can use the more succinct `if_else` instead. Not sure it's more readable this way. You can choose whether to keep `case_when` or not.

Comment: i need other conditions in my real example so I will keep `case_when` but good to know

Answer (score 2):

I've came up a solution that uses `sapply()` from base R.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(final_date = as.Date(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
    ifelse(is.na(df$final_date[x]), 
           ifelse(df$indicator[x] == 1, 
                  ifelse(is.na(df$id[x] == df$id[x + df$repeat_days[x]]),
                         format(as.Date(df$dates[x], origin = "2020-01-01")),
                         ifelse(df$id[x] == df$id[x + df$repeat_days[x]],
                                format(as.Date(df$dates[x + df$repeat_days[x]], origin = "2020-01-01")), 
                                NA)), 
                  NA), 
           as.character(df$final_date[x])))))

# A tibble: 15 × 5
      id dates      indicator final_date repeat_days
   <dbl> <date>         <dbl> <date>           <int>
 1     1 2015-01-01         0 2015-01-01           1
 2     1 2015-01-02         1 2015-01-03           2
 3     1 2015-01-02         0 NA                   2
 4     1 2015-01-03         1 2015-01-04           1
 5     1 2015-01-04         0 NA                   1
 6     2 2015-02-22         0 NA                   1
 7     2 2015-02-23         1 2015-02-25           3
 8     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
 9     2 2015-02-23         0 NA                   3
10     2 2015-02-25         0 NA                   1
11     3 2015-03-13         0 NA                   1
12     3 2015-03-14         1 2015-03-15           1
13     3 2015-03-15         0 NA                   1
14     4 2015-04-15         0 NA                   1
15     4 2015-04-16         1 2015-04-16           1
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like that as well; although this does not do it by group, does it? I mean, if a lead is outside the boundary of the group, it will pass to the other group while it should have NA.

Comment: @Maël Thanks for the reminder! I've included another `ifelse` to tackle this problem, but it's very very ugly.  Hope you or someone could provide a more elegant code :(

Comment: I unfortunately could not think of something better. Well done. +1. I actually am gonna delete my answer since it does not give a universal solution.

Comment: @benson23 thanks, +1, it doesn't quite do what I want (my fault as I have updated the question) and feel there is a shorter solution, happy to use `data.table` approaches too

Comment: @user63230 I've updated my code to fit your updated request. However, it makes the code even more ugly. I agree there should be a shorter solution.

Comment: the first row is incorrect - its tricky!

Comment: @user63230 Updated again. Since I sincerely believe this is badly written, I think this would be the last time I edit this piece of code, unless I have a better one :(